# Nested If AND statement where only some of the statements are returning true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a capacity tracker for my organisation whereby new starters are reflected at a reduced capacity throughout their induction. To do this I have an additional table next to the general capacity tracker that shows the start date vs the current date giving how many days the person has been working. This is then converted into 'months served' which is translated to a capacity adjustment. This adjustment is then used to divide their capacity by a set value per month, so 1 month served = an adjustment of 3 therefore their capacity is reduced to .3.

I am having some incorrect returns in my `IF`, `AND` statement which converts their days worked into months served. I am using the formula below, is there a better way to do this or could anyone spot the error in the formula? The first few statements are returning the correct answer but it goes wrong after 3 where the return '6+' when it should be 4.

```
=IF(
  AJ38<30,
  1,
  IF(
    AND(AJ38>30,AJ38<60),
    2,
    IF(
      AND(AJ38>61,AJ38<90),
      3,
      IF(
        AND(AJ38>91,AJ38<120),
        4,
        IF(
          AND(AJ38>121,AJ38<150),
          5,
          IF(
            AND(AJ38>151,AJ38<180),
            6,
            "6+"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I hope that makes sense, and thank you for your help!

Comment: I should add, the error is happening only one certain tabs (different tabs for each month) where the days in service is 90 and is returning '6+' when it should return 4. It is returning 4 as it should on other months. I have tried copying the formula from the correct tabs and pasting in to the broken tab but it stays as 6+

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved this. I had not accounted for when a value returns the actual figure of say '90'. Each statement was between 2 figures and so if the figure landed on an a whole number it was not accounted for. I have adjusted the ranges to be from 1 figure down and it is now working. Working formula -  =IF(AJ4<30,1,IF(AND(AJ4>29,AJ4<60),2,IF(AND(AJ4>59,AJ4<90),3,IF(AND(AJ4>89,AJ4<120),4,IF(AND(AJ4>119,AJ4<150),5,IF(AND(AJ4>149,AJ4<180),6,"6+"))))))

Comment: Would have been so much more readable with the `>=` and `<=` operators.

Comment: `=IF(AJ4 >= 180, "6+", QUOTIENT(AJ4, 30) + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

A few other possibilities:

1. Reduce the amount of layering by using [`IFS()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45) instead of nested `IF`. Note: This works in Excel 2016 or newer.

```
=ifs(AJ4<30,1,
     AND(AJ4>=30,AJ4<60),2,
     AND(AJ4>=60,AJ4<90),3,
     AND(AJ4>=90,AJ4<120),4,
     AND(AJ4>=120,AJ4<150),5,
     AND(AJ4>=150,AJ4<180),6,
     TRUE,"6+")
```

2. Use integer division to do it mathematically.

```
=INT(AJ4/30)+1
```

If you need that "6+" in there, you'll have to use an IF statement:

```
=IF(AJ4<180,INT(AJ4/30)+1,"6+")
```